# Determine Latent Mean with Effects-Coding Method using Confirmatory Factor Analysis

Tags: r, mean, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I'm currently working on a multiple-group confirmatory factor analysis using the R-package *lavaan*. The model has two latent variables with four indicators each. I've already established (partial) scalar invarince across the groups and now want to determine the latent mean values of the groups. To calculate the latent means, I plan to use the effect-coding method (Little, T. D., Slegers, D. W., & Card, 2006), which constrains the loadings of the indicators (per latent variable) to an average of 1.0 and the sum of the intercepts of indicators within each latent variable to 0.

I was already able to set the constrain for the factor loadings, but I'm struggeling with the syntax for the intercepts of the latent means to sum up to 0.

My question:

- How can I define my CFA-Model, so that the intercepts of indicators sum to zero? (within each latent variable)

Here's the model, for which I was able to constrain the factor loadings of the measured indicators to average to one.

```
model <- "
Beliefs =~ NA*item_1 + b1*item_1 + b2*item_2 + b3*item_3 + b4*item_4
Feelings =~ NA*item_5 + f1*item_5 + f2*item_6 + f3*item_7 + f4*item8

# loadings sum up to 1
b1 == 4 - b2 - b3 - b4
f1 == 4 - f2 - f3 - f4
"

fit <- lavaan::cfa(model, 
                   data = data,
                   group = "grouping_variable")


summary(fit, standardized = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

How can I further define my CFA-Model, so that the intercepts of the latent variables additionally sum up to zero?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I define my CFA-Model, so that the intercepts of indicators sum up to zero?

You would follow same process:

- Label each indicator's intercept
- Constrain 1 to be the complement of the sum of the others

Note from the `?model.syntax` help page that intercepts are defined by regressing on 1 (`variable ~ 1`).  For the first factor:

```
item_1 ~ foo1*1
item_2 ~ foo2*1
item_3 ~ foo3*1
item_4 ~ foo4*1

foo4 == -1*(foo1 + foo2 + foo3)
```

A single label implies it is equal across groups, but you said you had partial invariance, so at least 1 intercept must be different across groups.  In that case, you need a vector of labels for that intercept.  Then just define the constraint using invariant intercepts.

```
item_1 ~ foo1*1
item_2 ~ foo2*1
item_3 ~ c(foo3, bar3)*1 # different across 2 groups
item_4 ~ foo4*1

foo4 == -1*(foo1 + foo2) # only invariant intercepts
```

> How can I further define my CFA-Model, so that the intercepts of the latent variables additionally sum up to zero?

Not sure if you actually want to constrain latent intercepts/means to sum to zero, since they can all be freely estimated when identifying them with effects-coded intercepts.  But if you set `std.lv=TRUE` instead, then you can actually estimate all latent means under the same effects-coding constraint.  Not necessary because the latent location/scale is always arbitrary (contrary to Little et al.'s misleading title).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right, I made a mistake. The question is how to  constrain the intercepts of indicators to sum to zero? (within each latent variable). I will change that in the question.